# Waypoints with CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript, jquery-waypoints

I want to notify event based on scrolling. I found `Waypoints` which can solve my problem but I am getting all examples with `jQuery` and `Reactjs`. How can I use it in `CoffeeScript` ?

I am using below code. It is being fired everytime but i want it to fire only when it reaches at `waypoint-header`. I have this `div` in repeating mode, I mean this `div` is available after some list items (after each 20 items in list). Please help me to solve this.

```
$(window).scroll ->
        waypoint = new Waypoint(
            element: document.getElementById('waypoint-header'),
            handler:(direction) ->
                console.debug 'hello'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in CoffeeScript with no jQuery and React:

```
waypoint = new Waypoint
    element: document.getElementById('waypoint-header'),
    handler: (direction) ->
        console.log 'hello'
```

You don't need to add an event listener, Waypoints library does it itself.

[working codepen](https://codepen.io/mkhazov/pen/xrROdP)

Comment: It is being fired so many times based on scrolling. I want to fire `Waypoint` only when it reaches at `div` id waypoint-header.

Comment: @JeetenParmar, ahh I see, please take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: It is giving error `Error: No element option passed to Waypoint constructor`

Comment: One more thing, I have `<div id="waypoint-header">waypoint-header</div>` at many places in listing. I mean after each 20 items.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, it is normal for current code to be fired on any scroll event.
If you need just trigger once when reach to `waypoint-header` I guess, you should just create a waypoint without any scroll event as indicated [here](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/)

```
waypoint = new Waypoint
      element: document.getElementById('waypoint-header'),
      handler:(direction) ->
            console.debug 'hello'
```

To notify for each element inside list, I recommend to change id's to class and try this.

```
waypoint = $(".waypoint-header").waypoint ->
      element: document.getElementById('waypoint-header'),
      handler:(direction) ->
            console.debug 'hello'
```

Comment: It is giving error `Error: No element option passed to Waypoint constructor`

Comment: One more thing, I have `<div id="waypoint-header">waypoint-header</div>` at many places in listing. I mean after each 20 items.

Comment: so then element option should be distincted from the others I guess when looking at the complaint, you shouldn't use an `id` tag like `class`, `id` generally meant to be unique in document.

Comment: But I have listing and I want to call it every time I scroll down.

Comment: It is giving error. `TypeError: $(...).waypoint is not a function` I installed `waypoints` using `bower`.

Comment: You could double check if library and its dependencies  loaded properly

Comment: Would be helpful if you create a jsfiddle demo, and ensure that your code is supported by waypoint version as indicated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32001809/2289430